# Checking if a javascript object contains a poperty while ignoring case of the property

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I am using following code to form a object from query string

```
var parameters = Ext.urlDecode(urlParts[1]);
```

I know parameters conatins a property with the name 'OneTwo', but I am not sure about the case. I want to check the property of 'parameters' while ignoring the case.

so parameters.hasOwnProperty('oneTwo') or so parameters.hasOwnProperty('OneTwo') or so parameters.hasOwnProperty('ONETWO') or so parameters.hasOwnProperty('oNeTwo') should return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a for in loop

```
for (var prop in parameters){
    if (prop.toLowerCase() == 'onetwo'){
        alert('yay');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I wanted to access the value of property which i m doing like this now  for (var prop in parameters){
    if (prop.toLowerCase() == 'onetwo'){
        var value = parameters[prop];        break;
    }
}